# Use custom loss value while training in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to train my neural network using a custom loss value of my own. Therefore, I would like to perform feed forward propagation for one mini batch to store the activations in the memory, and then perform back propagation using a my own loss value. This is to be done using tensorflow.

Finally, I need to do something like:

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: training_data, loss: my_custom_loss_value}
```

Is that possible? I am assuming that the optimizer depends on the loss which by itself depends on the input. Therefore, I want to inputs to be fed into the graph, but I want to use my value for the loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since the optimizer depends on the activations, they will be evaluated, in other words, the input is going to be fed into the network. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(8.0))
a = tf.Print(input_=a, data=[a], message="a:")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(6.0))
b = tf.Print(input_=b, data=[b], message="b:")

c = a * b

optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(c)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    value, _ = sess.run([c, optimizer], feed_dict={c: 1})
    print(value)
```

Finally, the printed value is 1.0, while the console shows: `a:[8]b:[6]` which means that the inputs got evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly so.
When you train the `optimizer` using Gradient Descent or any other optimization algorithm like `AdamOptimizer()`, the optimizer minimizes your `loss` function, which could be a Softmax cross entropy `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in terms of multi-class classification, or a squared error loss `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` in terms of regression or your own custom loss. The `loss` function is evaluated or computed using the model hypothesis.

So TensorFlow uses this cascade approach to train the model hypothesis by calling a `tf.Session().run()` on the `optimizer`. See the following as a rough example in a multi-classification setting:

```
batch_size = 128

# build the linear model
hypothesis = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_X, weight), bias)

# softmax cross entropy loss or cost function for logistic regression
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets,
                          logits=hypothesis))

# optimizer to minimize loss
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(loss)

# execute in Session
with tf.Session() as sess:
     # initialize all variables
     tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
     tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

     # Train the model
     for steps in range(1000):
         mini_batch = zip(range(0, X_train.shape[0],  batch_size),
                    range(batch_size, X_train.shape[0]+1, batch_size))

         # train using mini-batches
         for (start, end) in mini_batch:
             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {input_X: X_features[start:end],
                                               input_y: y_targets[start:end]})
```